# How is it that Devise's current_user is accessible in an engine mounted in the app, and how can I accomplish the same with one of my methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I created a mountable engine, for which I'd like some routes to require authentication. I see that inside my engine's controller I have access to `current_user` ( defined by Devise ). How can I create such a method in my main app, and access it in the engine? Basically, I need a customizable auth method for my engine.